# Printing the addresses of variables in decimal

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax

I'm trying to print the addresses of the elments of an array in decimal instead of hexa but it doesn't work. Below is the code and output example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void printarrandptr(int arr[], int size);
const int LEN = 5;

void main(){

    int arr[LEN] = { 15, 3, 14, 11, 14 };

    int *p[LEN];

    printarrandptr((int*)arr, LEN);
}

void printarrandptr(int arr[], int size){
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << setw(9) << &arr[i] << setw(4) << arr[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

output example:

```
 0098FDC8  15
 0098FDCC   3
 0098FDD0  14
 0098FDD4  11
 0098FDD8  14
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a overload for `ostream& operqator<<(ostream&, void*)` that uses hex format by default.

`cout << setw(9) << (long long)&arr[i] ...` should do the trick.

---

<sub>Please no discussions about the c-style cast.</sub>

Comment: Oh right! so integers convert from hexa to dec automatically.

Comment: @kuhaku Updated my answer a bit to explain.

Comment: long isn't large enough to hold a pointer in 64-bit windows programs.

Comment: @kuhaku There's a difference between "it prints an integer" and "it prints the correct integer". You'll silently lose information if you cast a 64-bit pointer to a 32-bit int. And if you're being strictly standards compliant, casting a pointer directly to a smaller type is not allowed. I would recommend `uintptr_t` as ravi mentioned when you want to represent a pointer as an integer.

Comment: @0x5f3759df I just tried to compare using `long long` and `(uintptr_t)` and both show the same value as casting to an `int`, is it simply luck?

Comment: @kuhaku You're probably compiling a 32-bit binary (the default in Visual Studio). Even if you're on a 64-bit OS, a 32-bit binary will have 32-bit addresses. The size difference is why it's a good idea to use uintptr_t, it's *always* the right size to hold a pointer. It's also possible that your 64-bit address just happens to fit in 32 bits, but IIRC the usermode addressing scheme of Windows would make that unusual. The fact that casting to `int` compiles for you suggests the former, unless your compiler is violating 5.2.10p4 of the standard.

Answer (score 9):

Better and portable way would be :-

```
int arr[2] = {1,2};
uintptr_t number = (uintptr_t)&arr[0];
cout << number << endl;
```

Comment: If I were doing this in real code, I would prefer a `reinterpret_cast` here, but +1 for `uintptr_t`.